# How we can use onNewIntent() in any Activity?

Tags: android

What is the real use of `onNewIntent()` in the activity life cycle and how do we use this method?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag when calling startActivity(Intent).

If you set to single top, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack. It will not relaunch just show from stack.

Comment: Apparently this will also be called if `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` is used (does so in my code). Don't know why [the official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) don't mention it

Comment: Its **not only** for singleTop launch mode, but rather any time an *exciting* Activity instance gets launched from a new Intent.
For example it may also be called when using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ` or the 'singleTask' or 'singleInstance' launch modes.

Comment: @RobCo is correct. Only thing to note is he meant "existing", not "exciting"

Comment: How about singleTask?

Answer (score 33):

Check this link [onNewIntent()](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities)

In manifest.xml, in an activity tag set launchmode="singleTask"

Comment: very good link. it explains how onCreate and onNewIntent work in tandem

Comment: That link explains everything. It's way much better than Android its own documentation.

Comment: Link is dead now. :(

Answer (score 16):

Above answers are incomplete.

In case the activity 'a1' of Application 'A1' has launch mode "singleTask" or "singleTop" and is already alive (in task t1) but paused, and now another task (say Task t2) (usually another android app) sends an intent to activity a1 of application A1, then instead of creating another instance of activity in task t2, android resumes a1 from task t1, by issuing a callback to onNewIntent(intent) method in a1.

[Tasks and back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) is an important concept, no blog explains better than android documentation itself.