# Appending TextView from Service?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have an issue which I cannot seem to get my head around.  The background to it is that I am trying to update a view on an Android Wear device

I have a WearableListenerService called **MessageListener** which has an onMessageReceived function as follows:

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    Log.v("WEAR", "MessageListener Triggered");


    MessageObject msg = processMessageEvent(messageEvent);
    // handle only wear messages
    if (msg.getTarget().equals("wear")) {
        Log.v("WEAR:", "COMMAND RECEIVED: " + msg.getCommand());
        Log.v("WEAR:", "TARGET RECEIVED: " + msg.getTarget());
        Log.v("WEAR:", "MESSAGE RECEIVED: " + msg.getMessage());


        if (msg.getCommand().equals("SMS")) {
            Log.v("WEAR:", "SMS COMMAND RAN. " + msg.getMessage());
            // do something
        } else if (msg.getCommand().equals("CODE")) {
            // do something
            Log.v("WEAR:", "CODE RECEIVED:  " + msg.getMessage());

            Main.textCode.setText(msg.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine until it gets to

```
Main.textCode.setText(msg.getMessage());
```

where it crashes with a NullPointerException.  msg.getMessage is populated as it outputs the message into the verbose log as per the code.

In my Main class, I am declaring the textCode as a TextView,

```
public static TextView textCode;
```

and then in onCreate, I am setting the textCode to the xml element:

```
textCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCode);
```

The full error is:

> 08-20 13:45:41.689    2248-2262/com.domain.cinesaver E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: WearableListenerService
>       Process: com.domain.cinesaver, PID: 2248
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at com.domain.cinesaver.MessageListener.onMessageReceived(MessageListener.java:50)
>               at com.google.android.gms.wearable.WearableListenerService$a$2.run(Unknown
>   Source)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

Comment: id `textCode` is inside fragment?

Comment: No, its with the Main class which extends Activity

Comment: What line is line 50 in `MessageListener` class?

Comment: @Sirlate             Main.textCode.setText(msg.getMessage());

Comment: Can you check that `msg.getMessage()` is returning null or not?

Comment: I'm writing to the log: Log.v("WEAR:", "MESSAGE RECEIVED: " + msg.getMessage());   If I look in the log, I have  V/WEAR:﹕ CODE RECEIVED:  55577768 so msg is not null

Comment: your textview is null. check where you are initializing it and where you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to send a new Intent with some extra values to the activity and change you UI.

[This question may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357200/how-we-can-use-onnewintent-in-any-activity)

For you activity receive intent new to be on manifest.xml need to have this

```
<activity android:name=".acitvity"  launchmode="singleTask"/>
```

And you when you send the intent and the values you need on you activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,acitvity.class);

intent.putExtra("key","value");

getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `TextView` reference is `static`, but it shouldn't be. The TextView relies on the lifecycle of the activity, so it relies on a state of the activity, which means that it should be bound to the object, not to the class itself.
Remove the `static` qualifier and implement a listener interface or something similar in order to notify your activity's object about the reception of this message. Then the activity itself will decide what to do when this message is received, i.e. when the listener gets fired.