# Why is onDestroy() called when I click on a notification and go to my activity?

Tags: android, android-notifications

Why is onDestroy() called when I click on a notification and go to my activity? The control flow goes like this -> onCreate -> onStart -> onResume -> onDestroy. The following is my code for adding notification:-

```
private void addNotification(String message, User user, String roomId) {
    System.out.println("Inside addNotif service");
    if (message.length()==0) {
        return;
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("2222----You have new message(s)");
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent notificationIntent;

    if (roomId.contains("admin1")) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DemoChatActivity.class);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, copyDemoChatActivity.class);
    }
    //notificationIntent.putExtra(com.clover_studio.spikachatmodule.utils.Const.Extras.USER, user);
    Config config = new Config(com.clover_studio.spikachatmodule.utils.Const.Api.BASE_URL, com.clover_studio.spikachatmodule.utils.Const.Socket.SOCKET_URL);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(com.clover_studio.spikachatmodule.utils.Const.Extras.CONFIG, config);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(com.clover_studio.spikachatmodule.utils.Const.Extras.ROOM_ID, roomId);


    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

My onDestroy() method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    System.out.println("copyDemoChat - onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "unregistering reciever");
    // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
    Intent intentN = new Intent(copyDemoChatActivity.this, com.clover_studio.democloverapp.Utils.SSNotificationService.class);
    copyDemoChatActivity.this.startService(intentN);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    isRunningCDCA = false;
}
```

Comment: May be This code create new Activity. So previous will be Destroy.. You can get new intent in `onNewIntent()` in existing Activity.

Comment: On your direction, I searched a bit about onNewIntent() and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357200/how-we-can-use-onnewintent-in-any-activity). This led me to [this link](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/communicating-between-running-activities). But sadly, even after implementing the onNewIntent() method, the onDestroy() function was called.

Comment: OK, so my onNewIntent() method is not getting called only! How to ensure that it is called if the activity I am going to is already present in background?

Comment: Can i know what you have done in `onDestroy` method ?

Comment: @MayurRaval - Edited the question to show the onDestroy() method

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre, check launch mode in manifest file, it its standard then onDestroy will call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Pass some putExtra String in Notiification like

```
if (roomId.contains("admin1")) {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, DemoChatActivity.class);
    } else {
        notificationIntent = new Intent(this, copyDemoChatActivity.class);
    }
notificationIntent.putExtra("From","Notification");
```

In your Activity, Where your `onDestory()`method implemented , maintain one flag

```
     boolean isFromNotification = false;
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            onNewIntent(getIntent());
        }

    @Override
     protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       super.onNewIntent(intent);
       String tmString = intent.getExtra().getString("From");
        isFromNotification = tmString.equalsIgnoreCase("Notification");
      }
```

And in `onDestroy`Method

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      if(!isFromNotification ){
        System.out.println("copyDemoChat - onDestroy()");
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "unregistering reciever");
        // Unregister since the activity is about to be closed.
        Intent intentN = new Intent(copyDemoChatActivity.this, com.clover_studio.democloverapp.Utils.SSNotificationService.class);
        copyDemoChatActivity.this.startService(intentN);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        isRunningCDCA = false;

      }
      isFromNotification =false;
    }
```

If Any issue let me Know.

Comment: Where is the "if" ending?

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre, Sorry for code mistake, Just edited

Comment: It worked! Had to do some changes, like before "equalsIgnoreCase", had to add a check whether the string is null or not and had to take out the super.onDestroy() out of the "if", otherwise an exception was thrown.

Comment: When I run this conditional, I get hit with SuperNotCalledException. Did you get around that somehow?

Comment: @Alon, may be this error is from `onDestroy()` method .. you can try it by putting `super.onDestroy();` out of the `if` condition.